# How to make a button so that it can only be dragged to a certain extent?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I wanted to know if it was possible to make it so that when you mouseover a button to move it either to the right or to the left, it moved only 200px. So that once it is moved 200px it can't be moved another 200px, but once it is moved back to it's original position it can be moved 200px again.

I have this javascript code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[

// window.onload=function() {
//    document.getElementById("d2").onmouseover = slideIt("toRight");
//    document.getElementById("d3").onmouseover = slideIt("toLeft");
// };

function slideIt(actionReturn) {
    var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("d1");
    var stopPosition = 50;
    var startPosition = slidingDiv.offsetWidth+slidingDiv.offsetWidth;
    if (actionReturn ==  "toRight") {
        if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) >= 0 )
        {
            slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) - 200 + "px";
            setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
        }
    }
    if (actionReturn ==  "toLeft") {
        if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) < startPosition ) {
            slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 200 + "px";
            setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
        }
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I have removed the C# tag and added other tags which seeem to be more appropriate. Feel free to edit it again if `ASP.NET` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define three flags (i.e. three variables) to track the movements; such that you need to define one which indicates that the button is in its original location, one to indicate that the button has shifted to right, and one to indicate that the button has shifted to left. These variables will hold boolean values (true, false). At each slide you need to check these flags to specify if the shift will actually occur or not.

Here is a suggested update to your code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 var isInOriginalPosition = true;
 var isShiftedToRight = false;
 var isShiftedToLeft = false;

 function slideIt(actionReturn) {
    var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("d1");
    var stopPosition = 50;
    var startPosition = slidingDiv.offsetWidth+slidingDiv.offsetWidth;
    if (actionReturn ==  "toRight") {
        if (isShiftedToRight && !isInOriginalPosition)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (isShiftedToLeft && !isInOriginalPosition)
        {
            slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) - 200 + "px";
            setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
            isShiftedToLeft = false;
            isInOriginalPosition = true;
        }
        else if (isInOriginalPosition)
        {
            slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) - 200 + "px";
            setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
            isShiftedToRight = true;
            isInOriginalPosition = false;
        }
    }
    if (actionReturn ==  "toLeft") {
        if (isShiftedToLeft && !isInOriginalPosition)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (isShiftedToRight && !isInOriginalPosition)
        {
            slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 200 + "px";
            setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
            isShiftedToRight = false;
            isInOriginalPosition = true;
        }
        else if (isInOriginalPosition)
        {
            slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 200 + "px";
            setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
            isShiftedToLeft = true;
            isInOriginalPosition = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please check my added code in the edited version. Just go into different slide movements to make sure it works properly :)

Comment: thank you! i had to change 2 of the flags and it was perfect!

Comment: using this code, I can't shift it to the right more than 1 time. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Well, is it required from your page to allow the button to be shifted to the right/left many times? what is the number of allowed attempts for shifting?

Comment: Before I changed the script I was able to shift it back and forth however many times I wanted to

Comment: Sorry, I understood from your problem description that you need to restrict the movement to right/left from the original position for only one step. Anyhow, if your original code was properly shifting the button many times, and this is what you are trying to get, what is the problem? Can you specify in details what is the expected behavior from shifting the button?

Comment: i would like the button to shift to the right once and then be able to shift to the left once, but be able to do it mulptiple times. Before, it could shift to the right 3 times and then shift to the left 6, for example.

Comment: It worked fine with me. Just make sure to take the code as I posted it. Make sure that the variables are declared outside the method, not inside it.